# Trigger conditional

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I would like to make a SQL Trigger that will evaluate a query like this:

```
IF NOT (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id=1 AND table1.finished=0)   
DO 
UPDATE table2 SET finished=1 WHERE table2.id=table1.id
```

That would tell me that all rows from table1 with an id of 1 are finished (if there are no unfinished(0) rows) and, if so, it should update table2 and set the value finished to 1.

Can anyone help me with the Trigger structure? I'm new when it comes to that.

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Try something,post it here,people will help.I want stuff it`s not really a question.

Comment: @Mihai The code presented in my question is my best try at the trigger logic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tg_au_table1
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT OLD.finished <=> NEW.finished THEN
    UPDATE table2 t
       SET finished = (EXISTS(SELECT * 
                                FROM table1 
                               WHERE id = t.id 
                                 AND finished = 0))
     WHERE id = NEW.id;
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b657/1)** demo

Extended answer is provided in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/21270582/1920232