# Trigger: Referencing updated attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

I have a Trigger on UPDATE.

What is the correct procedure for referencing attribute from the table that is not updated by the UPDATE SQL command? Is the attribute still in the UPDATE variable? I would like to get the value of that attribute for the updated row.

Comment: Your question in its current state is very unclear. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you mean: get value of column B when column A is updated (for each updated row)?

Comment: @bd33 I know I can access the updated attribute using UPDATED.attribute_name. But what if that attribute is not updated in the query. I would like to know the value of that attribute for the updated row. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a values of a column before update and after update in MySQL by using keywords `OLD` and `NEW`.

For example if you want to determine whether a value of a column actually has been changed during updated you can do

```
IF NOT OLD.column_name <=> NEW.column_name THEN
    -- do something here
END IF;
```

**Note:** `<=>` is NULL-safe comparison operator in MySQL

**BTW:** There is no `UPDATED` virtual table in MySQL. It's from SQL Server.

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19ecd0/1)** demo. *Note that even though update affected all records in the table, only one message has been logged in `log` table. It's because value for a row with id 2 in the end stayed the same.*

---

**UPDATE:** to keep your `finished` flag in sync you need triggers for all events (insert, update, delete).

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_event
AFTER INSERT ON event
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE activity a
     SET status = (EXISTS(SELECT * 
                            FROM event 
                           WHERE activity = a.activity_id
                             AND done = 0))
   WHERE activity_id = NEW.activity;
END//

CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_event
AFTER DELETE ON event
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE activity a
     SET status = (EXISTS(SELECT * 
                            FROM event 
                           WHERE activity = a.activity_id 
                             AND done = 0))
   WHERE activity_id = OLD.activity;
END//

CREATE TRIGGER tg_au_event
AFTER UPDATE ON event
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT OLD.activity <=> NEW.activity THEN
    -- if activity id was changed for an event then clculate finished flag
    -- for both old and new activity id
    UPDATE activity a
       SET status = (EXISTS(SELECT * 
                              FROM event 
                             WHERE activity = a.activity_id 
                               AND done = 0))
     WHERE activity_id IN(OLD.activity, NEW.activity);
  ELSE
    -- otherwise calculate finished flag only if done flag is changed 
    IF NOT OLD.done <=> NEW.done THEN
      UPDATE activity a
         SET status = (EXISTS(SELECT * 
                                FROM event 
                               WHERE activity = a.activity_id 
                                 AND done = 0))
       WHERE activity_id = NEW.activity;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c05d/1)** demo

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me why I'm getting this error in MySQL
The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`administ`@`localhost` TRIGGER `on_event_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `event` FOR EACH ROW IF NOT (SELECT * FROM event WHERE event.activity=OLD.activity AND event.done = 0) THEN UPDATE activity SET activity.status = 0 WHERE activity.activity_id=OLD.activity END IF;"

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 3

Comment: It's because you didn't use `BEGIN ... END`  block which you should because your trigger's body contains more than one statement.

Comment: If you explain the logic that you want to enforce with a trigger I can help you with it.

Comment: My current logic:

CREATE DEFINER=`administ`@`localhost` TRIGGER `on_event_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `event` IF NOT (SELECT * FROM event WHERE event.activity=OLD.activity AND event.done = 0) THEN UPDATE activity SET activity.status = 0 WHERE activity.activity_id=OLD.activity END IF;

Comment: If all events for the activity are finished then the activity is finished. my trigger logic is following: IF NOT (statement that is false only when there are NO unfinished events for that activity), then I update the activity and make it finished.

Comment: See updated answer for extended example of how your triggers code might look like.